# File upload SendKyes not working Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Trying to upload file using chromedriver
I findelement Browse button and Click() to uploadfile
new window opens for entering the path I use SendKyes doesn't type the filepath to

WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.name("btnChooseFiles"));
fileInput.sendKeys("C:/path/to/file.jpg");

here is the HTML code

```
<div style="height: inherit; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
                            <input name="fileInput" type="file" id="fileInput" onpropertychange="add()" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;" multiple="true">
                            <input type="submit" name="btnChooseFiles" value="Browse..." onclick="fileInput.click();return false;" id="btnChooseFiles" class="bluebutton bluebutton32 browsebutton">
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To send keys use the following code instead:

```
string keysToPress = "asdf";
var webDriver = new WebDriver();
var actions = new Actions(webDriver);
actions.SendKeys(keysToPress).Perform();
```

Comment: I assume the KeysToPress is the path to file to be uploaded right?    it did not work for me I am getting the same result as SendKyes. the file path still shows empty

Comment: If the window you are talking about is not in the browser then i dont think sending keys through webdriver is going to give you the functionality you need